# Swift: Filter array of array of Object

Tags: arrays, swift

I have the following structure

```
aSectionArray = [[objA, objB, objC], [obj1, obj2, obj3], [objX, objY, objZ]]
```

objA is having a bool, say `isEnabled`.

I need to filter the `aSectionArray` based this bool (say `isEnabled == true`).

Help needed.

Comment: What do you want to achieve through the filter? Do you want all objects where isEnabled is true?

Comment: What's the array's type?

Comment: Not clear if you're wanting to flatten and filter as Eric suggests, or return only the elements of the outer array that have a matching element, or an array of arrays of matching objects, or...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `flatten()` and `filter`, like this (Swift 2):

```
let result = aSectionArray.flatten().filter { $0.isEnabled }
```

it will give you the objects where `isEnabled` is true.

We use `flatten()` to make the 2D array into a 1D array, and we use `filter` to get the objects where the closure verifies.

In Swift 3 (Xcode 8 beta 6) `flatten` has become `joined`:

```
let result = aSectionArray.joined().filter { $0.isEnabled }
```